# "Delete product from cart" button doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I have problem with delete product from cart button in Spree app.
I have a cart and there is partial _line_item.html.erb:

```
<%= order_form.fields_for :line_items, line_item do |item_form| %>
  <tr class="first odd">
    <td class="image"><a class="product-image" title="Sample Product" href="#/women-s-crepe-printed-black/">
      <% if variant.images.length == 0 %>
        <%= link_to small_image(variant.product), variant.product %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(variant.images.first.attachment.url(:small)), variant.product %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><h2 class="product-name">
      <%= link_to line_item.name, product_path(variant.product) %>
       </h2>
    </td>
    <td class="a-center"><a title="Edit item parameters" class="edit-bnt" href="#configure/id/15945/"></a></td>
    <td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"> <span class="price">
      <%= line_item.single_money.to_html %></span> </span>
    </td>
    <td class="a-center movewishlist">
      <%= item_form.number_field :quantity, min: 0, class: "form-control line_item_quantity", size: 5 %>
    </td>
    <td class="a-right movewishlist"><span class="cart-price"> <span class="price">
      <%= line_item.display_amount.to_html unless line_item.quantity.nil? %></span> </span>
    </td>
    <td class="a-center last cart-item-delete ">
      <%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign'), '#', class: 'delete', id: "delete_#{dom_id(line_item)}" %>
    </td>
  </tr>

<% end %>
```

Last table cell refers to delete product from cart button but when click on that nothing happens with that cart

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign'), '#', class: 'delete', id: "delete_#{dom_id(line_item)}" %>
```

Comment: It links to nowhere (because of '#'), maybe it should work with js? I haven't knowledge about spree, but such link can't work

Comment: Official docs [link_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) shows that you should specify `action` and `controller`  alongside the `id`. Example: `link_to "Profile", controller: "profiles", action: "show", id: @profile`. In your case something like `<%= link_to content_tag(...), line_item_path(line_item),  method: :delete %>` should also work. Check this great [article](https://rubyplus.com/articles/2811-Rails-5-Basics-Delete-Article)

Answer (score 0):

Consider to add

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

to layouts/spree_application.html.erb

Also, make sure to add in your assets pipeline... assets/javascripts/spree/frontend.js looks like this

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs 
    //= require spree
    //= require spree/frontend/checkout
    //= require spree/frontend/product
    //= require spree/frontend/cart
    //= require spree/frontend/locale_selector
```

this shoud work fine with:

'<%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign'), '#', class: 'delete', id: "delete_#{dom_id(line_item)}" %>'

Comment: it's still not working. I note that I put all js files in assets/javascripts/spree/frontend folder and I'm using Spree 3.0

Answer (score 0):

It may work:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign'), line_item_path(line_item), method: :delete, class: 'delete', id: "delete_#{dom_id(line_item)}" %>
```

Comment: It's not working. I got a NoMethodError: undefined method `line_item_path'

Comment: How is your `config/routes.rb` file?

Comment: mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/' is all I have